# regEx: extract specifics out of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse a specific piece of info out of a string using javascript.
I can do it using .split() method, but I feel regex can be more efficient.
However, this one is a bit over my head.

this is the string (whitespaces included):

```
      AZUCAR FLORENCIA CAQUETA                                       875783       181038       111155       805900
```

I only want

```
AZUCAR FLORENCIA CAQUETA 805900
```

Comment: It's hard to tell the criteria to match with the regexp when you just give one example. What is the rule?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple

```
string.split(/\s{1,}/).join(' ')
```

Search for 2 or more whitespace characters, and replace them with an empty string. This effectively deletes it from the string.

Answer (score 0):

One solution :

```js
var str = '      AZUCAR FLORENCIA CAQUETA                                       875783       181038       111155       805900';
var result = str.replace(/^\s*([A-Za-z ]*[A-Za-z] )(.*)([0-9]{6}$)/gi , '$1$3' );
console.log(result);
document.getElementById('el').innerHTML = result;
```

```css
#el{
  border : solid 1px #CCC;
  padding : 3px;
  margin : 3px;
  }
```

```html
<div id='el'><div>
```